# Who calls constructor in virtual inheritance?

Tags: c++, object, virtual, multiple-inheritance, vtable

```
#include<iostream>

class base{
public:
base(){std::cout<<"In base";}
};

class dv1:virtual private base {
public:
dv1(){std::cout<<"In DV1";}
};

class dv2:virtual private base {
public:
dv2(){std::cout<<"In DV2";}
};

class drv : public dv1, public dv2 {
public:
drv() {std::cout<<"Why is this working";}
};

int main() {
drv obj;

return 0;
}
```

Isn't in case of virtual inheritance, it is the responsibility of most derive class to call the constructor?
Note: Here base is inherited virtually and privately.

Comment: and what is the output vs. what you were expecting? If you were expecting something different, I suggest you go back and revisit the chapter on inheritance and try to understand that first.

Comment: i expecting it not to compile as the base is derived virtually and Privately.

Answer (score 5):

Your constructor of `drv` didn't explicitly call the constructors of its base class(es), so the compiler will generate a call to the parameterless constructor of the base class

Comment: Thats right... But how is it able to do so?

Comment: `base::base()` is public so `drv` has access to this constructor. The fact that `base` is a private base of `dv1` and `dv2` isn't relevant.